# Как ограничить SFTP пользователя корневой папкой?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, chroot

Есть необходимость создать на сервере несколько ftp аккаунтов, сейчас 3, в будущем больше. Выбрал sftp из-за надежности.

Как ограничить пользователей конкретной директорией так, что бы они не имели возможности подняться выше?

Сейчас использую `ChrootDirectory`. И с ним есть одна важная для меня проблема.
У директории для чрута должны быть права, ограничивающие запись для пользователя. Это значит что для корректного использования, придется создать внутри этой папки вспомогательную, например "domains" и уже в ней предоставить пользователю все права. Это выглядит очень криво и не элегантно. Я хочу что бы человек получив логин/пароль чувствовал себя как дома и мог создать любую структуру директорий, в том числе в корне предоставленной ему директории.

Есть ли решение?

И ещё один вопрос. Пока гуглил, наткнулся на [хабростатью](https://habr.com/post/141012/) о том, как выйти из чрута. Сути не понял и пока что ничего не проверял. Достаточно надежен ли чрут для разграничения доступа нескольким пользователям или возможность залезть в чужую директорию существует?

Comment: lshell может пригодится?

Comment: @eri у моих пользователей нет доступа к консоли (`/bin/false`) и быть не должно. Судя по всему, для этой задачи придется использовать ftp...

Comment: а если смонтировать каталог с nodev,nosuid,acl и аксес листом разрешить запрещенный rw

Comment: @eri если в каталог может писать кто-то кроме рута, то выбрасывается ошибка. Если я правильно все понял, это сделано так потому, что при возможности записи в корень чрута, можно из него выбраться. Видимо придется выбирать между удобством и безопасностью

Comment: может есть авто cd

Comment: @eri не додумался это загуглить. Действительно есть (`ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /путь_относительно_чрута` если кому-нибудь интересно). Но это все же не то. Можно выйти в корень чрута и выяснить что создавать файлы/папки там нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил для этих целей докер контейнеры. В этом решении очень изолировано на уровне ядра. Плюс каждый может быть у себя в контейнере делать что угодно.
Все необходимые папки можно смаунтить. Минус этого решения лишь в том, что для sft необходимо будет другие порты указывать для каждого пользака.

Comment: Слишком сложно для такой простой задачи. В этом случае лично мне было бы проще арендовать ещё несколько серверов, каждый для отдельного пользователя. Мне нужно то что есть сейчас, но с возможностью создавать файлы и папки в корневой директории чрута

Comment: докер контейнеры плохи тем что там есть свой кусок ос, который пользователи любят ломать, а потом пинать техподдержку..)

Comment: они хороши тем что образ можно создать тот, который нужен со всей кухней.
Ну даже если что то сломают. Всегда можно восстановить из образа в одну команду/скриптом или еще чем нибудь.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev все это я могу сделать и с AWS EC2, разницы ровным счетом нет вообще. Я спрашивал о настройке sftp, а не о отдельном окружении для пользователя. У моих пользователей вообще нет доступа к консоли (`/bin/false`) и быть не должно. Их задача создавать и редактировать файлы.

Comment: Кроме чрутинга ничего не приходит в голову.